# Iteration algorithm with lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've started Python coding recently and decided to make a short program. A year ago I took a History exam, the first task in it was to put three events in a chronological order. I want to recreate this task with a program that randomizes these events, so that it has a potential of generating thousands of unique tasks like that (years shouldn't be seen in the actual program):

1.Copper Riot (1662)

2.The Battle of Kulikovo (1380)

3.The First Crusade (1096)

I managed to do this. But every task has an answer. It is stored in a list called *years*. There is another list, called *syears*, which has it sorted in a chronological order.

```
years = [1662, 1497, 1096]
syears = [1096, 1497, 1662]
```

There is a variable called *answer* that should store the correct answer.
The correct answer would be: ***321***

But I have a problem with a program getting the correct answer, I decided just to bruteforce it:

```
answer = 0

if years[0] == syears[0]:
  # answer = '1'
  if years[1] == syears[1]:
    # answer = '12'
    if years[2] == syears[2]:
      answer = '123'
  else:
      answer = '132'
elif years[1] == syears[1]:
  # answer = '2'
  if years[0] == syears[0]:
    # answer = '21'
    if years[2] == syears[2]:
      answer = '213'
  else:
      answer = '231'

And so on...
```

However, it doesn't work. Moreover, I suspect it's bad coding. What are the rational options of getting the correct answer using these two lists? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding the index of each element is best done in a loop, like so:

```
answer = []
for syear in syears:
    idx = years.index(syear)
    answer.append(idx)
```

(The indexes here will be zero-based. Add 1 to each of them if you want them to be one-based).

Of course, there are many many other ways to do what you are trying to do here. Including a one-line list comprehension like this one that avoids the need for `syears` altogether:

```
answer = [idx for idx, elem in sorted(enumerate(years), key=lambda x: x[1])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the list's `index` method

```
[years.index(value) + 1 for value in syears]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way of doing it without using the syears.

```
p = sorted(range(1,len(years)+1), key=lambda k: years[k-1])

print("".join([str(i) for i in p]))

#### Output ####
321
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you will have always a different order:

```
from random import shuffle

def gimmeThreeEvents():
    events = [
    ["Copper Riot", 1662],
    ["The Battle of Kulikovo",1380],
    ["The First Crusade",1096]
    ]
    shuffle(events)
    order = [x[1] for x in events]
    sort = sorted(order)
    print(order)
    print(sort)
    print("Order this events:")
    for e in events:
        print("- " + str(e[0]))
    print("Solutions:")
    sol = []
    for dates in order:
        sol.append(sort.index(dates) + 1)
    print(sol)
    return events

gimmeThreeEvents()
```

Output:

```
Order this events:
- The Battle of Kulikovo
- Copper Riot
- The First Crusade
Solutions:
[2, 3, 1]
[Finished in 0.1s]
```